# What exactly is %sysfunction in sas and what could it be used for

Tags: sas

What exactly is %sysfunction in sas and what could it be used for. Is it that it has many functions and we could use those functions for various getting results.

Answer (score 0):

It's a macro function that can execute various inherent SAS functions or user custom made functions. However, I believe function inside cannot be a macro function. And there are also some other exceptions, such as you cannot use `input` with `%sysfunction`. In `%sysfunc`, a format can also be applied to the output of the function that is being executed. Here are papers by Chris Yindra and Paul Hamilton outlining the usage: (imo. the latter is more clearer)

- http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi23/Advtutor/p44.pdf
- http://www.lexjansen.com/pnwsug/2005/how/SysFunc.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The SAS macro language only has around 30 builtin functions.  `%sysfunc` allows you to access the 100s of standard SAS functions from within the macro language.